# Directional Friction

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I want to have the friction of a Physic Material depend on the direction. I found [this documentation from Unity 5.2](https://docs.unity3d.com/520/Documentation/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html) that lets you set two directions and friction coefficients but that is missing from [the newest api](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html). Is there a way to do this in the new version or am I going to have to do it manually?

I'm trying to use wheel colliders to provide similar functionality but they are behaving very strangely. They fall through the floor, jump unexpectedly, bounce weirdly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question as I was having the same problem a while back!

Unfortunately, what I have gathered from both unity developers and the current documentation is that the feature you described is not implemented into the current Unity engine as you have assumed.

Some work arounds that I would suggest is reverting back to a previous version of the engine if you are able or create your own friction system that would take data from the velocity vector of a physics object to determine which direction it is travelling. More information on finding a Physics object's velocity can be found on this page https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html

Best of luck on your Unity Project!